# Default page size for Google docs

Tags: api, documents

We have a system that generates documents using the Google API, we would like the page set-up to default to A4 for all documents we generate. We have set the default as A$ in the Google Doc settings but this doesn't carry through for files created using the API.

Is there something we need to set in the API call to generate the doc?

Thanks in advance,
David

Answer (score 0):

> Is there something we need to set in the API call to generate the doc?

Unfortunately it looks like this option isn't supported via the API, either on file creation or on file update. Google Docs/Drive treats page setup as an application setting as opposed to a per-file setting.

Here's the full list of metadata that you can specify about a file: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files